# AWS Lambda bootstrap.py file is throwing error while trying to upload data to elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I'm trying to index pdf documents that are uploaded to s3 bucket. My lambda function is working fine til PDF extraction part. it's establishing connection with elastic search endpoint and while uploading data elastic search for indexing, it's throwing error. Please find lambda function code below. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import boto3
import slate
import elasticsearch
import datetime

es_endpoint = 'search-sdjsf-zrtisx]sdaswasfsjmtsyuih3awvu.us-east- 
1.es.amazonaws.com'
es_index = 'pdf_text_extracts'
es_type = 'document'

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# prepare a dict to hold our document data
doc_data = {}
doc_data['insert_time'] = 
str(datetime.datetime.isoformat(datetime.datetime.now()))


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object'] 
    ['key']).decode('utf8')
    try:
        # get the file data from s3
        temp_pdf_file = open('/tmp/tempfile.pdf', 'w') 
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=object_key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
        # return response['ContentType']
        temp_pdf_file.write(response['Body'].read()) # write the object data 
        to a local file; will be passed to slate
        temp_pdf_file.close() # close the temporary file for now

        # pull the text from the temporary PDF file using slate
        print("Extracting data from: " + object_key)
        with open('/tmp/tempfile.pdf') as temp_pdf_file:

        doc = slate.PDF(temp_pdf_file)

        # store document data to dict
        doc_data['source_pdf_name'] = object_key
        doc_data['document_text'] = doc[0] # we're only worried about page 1 
        at this point

        #datj=json.dumps(doc_data)
        #z=json.loads(datj)
        #print(z)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist 
        and your bucket is in the same region as this 
        function.'.format(object_key, bucket))
        raise e

    # put the data in ES
    #try:
    es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch([{'host': es_endpoint, 'port': 443, 
   'use_ssl': True}]) # hold off on validating certs
    es_response = es.index(index=es_index, doc_type=es_type, body=doc_data)
    print('Data posted to ES: ' + str(es_response))

    #except Exception as e:
        #print('Data post to ES failed: ' + str(e))
        #raise e   

return "Done"
```

I have removed try and except in last block to find the actual error and its throwing the below error while trying to upload data to elastic search.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 576, in <module>
main()
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 571, in main
handle_event_request(request_handler, invokeid, event_body, context_objs, 
invoked_function_arn)
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 264, in 
handle_event_request
result = report_fault_helper(invokeid, sys.exc_info(), None)
File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 315, in report_fault_helper
msgs = [str(value), etype.__name__]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return "Done"` at the end, that's not allowed in a Lambda environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Milan Cermak. I have tried removing this, but it's giving same error